# Array is Returning NULL

Tags: java

My piece of code..

```
package com.xchanging.selenium.utility;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.ArrayUtils;

public class DataProviderConvertor extends ReadExcel {

    public static Object[][] convertData(String sheetName, String testCaseName)
            throws IOException {

        LinkedHashMap<String, String> table = ReadExcel.getData(sheetName,
                testCaseName);
        String[] myStringArray = new String[table.size()];
        for (String key : table.values()) {
            System.out.println("Keyvalues " + key.toString());
            String value = key.toString();
            ArrayUtils.add(myStringArray, value);
        }
        System.out.println("1st Index: " myStringArray[0]);
    }
  }
```

It is returning

```
Keyvalues Y
Keyvalues ie
Keyvalues QC 
Keyvalues Yes
Keyvalues Rework Checklist Comments
Keyvalues Yes
Keyvalues MRI Updated Comments


1st Index: null
```

I am expecting 6 elements in this array but all are returning NULL.. Why it is not returning the expected values..??

Comment: where are you returning btw

Comment: @ChanGan just two changes required, code is fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
for (String key : table.values()) {
     System.out.println("Keyvalues " + key.toString());
     String value = key.toString();
     myStringArray =ArrayUtils.addAll(myStringArray, value);
}
```

Or

```
int cnt=0;

for (String key : table.values()) {
         System.out.println("Keyvalues " + key.toString());
         String value = key.toString();
         myStringArray[cnt++] =value;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

How about much simpler way.

```
public static Object[][] convertData(String sheetName, String testCaseName)
        throws IOException {

    LinkedHashMap<String, String> table = ReadExcel.getData(sheetName,
            testCaseName);

    String[] myStringArray = table.values().toArray( new String[ 0 ] );

    System.out.println("1st Index: " + myStringArray[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**ArrayUtil.add** method copies the array and then adds the new element at the end of the new copied array.

So, i think that's where the problem lies in your code.

That is why myStringArray is showing the size as 0.As the myStringArray is copied and a new string array is formed and then the element is added to it.

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayUtils.add(myStringArray, value);
```

This method creates and **returns a new array** with the `value` added to it.

You need to assign the result:

```
myStringArray = ArrayUtils.add(myStringArray, value);
```

It has to be done that way because arrays cannot be resized.

Comment: The method add(String[], String) is undefined for the type DataProviderConvertor

Answer (score 0):

You can try this -:

```
int index =0;

for (String key : table.values()) {
            System.out.println("Keyvalues " + key.toString());
            String value = key.toString();
            myStringArray[index++] = value;            
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just two changes required, code is perfectly fine otherwise.

1.) `String[] myStringArray = new String[table.size()];`, change to

```
String[] myStringArray = null;
```

2.) `ArrayUtils.add(myStringArray, value);` change to

```
myStringArray = ArrayUtils.add(myStringArray, value);
```

Rest you can read and debug about this method [in API](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/ArrayUtils.html).